# Компиляция программы на C для платформы MIPS с порядком байтов big-endian

Tags: c, mips

Задача - установить прокси на модем D-Link.

Что делал и к чему пришел... Скажу сразу, с Си никогда не работал, почитал несколько дней справку, что-то отложилось... Поэтому, с нуля писать не решился, взял готовое решение `Satanic Socks Server`. Единственное, поменял `pthread` на `fork`, т.к. не смог найти исходников и рабочей библиотеки для MIPS (пробовал пару бинарников - не завелись).

Скомпилировал под CentOS_x86 - прокси работает. Собрал под `MIPS`, залил на модем, прокси запускается, порт открывается, прокси не работает.
Посмотрел сниффером (опять же пошел изучать протоколы `TCP/IP`), получилось, что клиент (браузер) закрывает соединение, стал изучать пакет от `SOCKS`, предшествующий закрытию. Сравнивал работу с `x86` и с `MIPS`. Насколько понял, там передается версия сервера. В x86: `0x0500`, в MIPS: `0x0005`. Перечитал прошивку - точно, используется `big-endian`, в то время как в x86 - `little-endian`.

Компилятор взял из исходников к той же модели модема. Стал читать справку к нему. Есть опции `-meb` и `-mel` для big и little. Попробовал `-meb` - получилось то же самое, `-mel` не пошло - заругался на неверный формат одной из библиотек. Да и смысла нет делать с `little-endian`, если прошивка собрана с `big`.

Собственно вопрос: Как собрать программу для системы с `big-endian`, чтобы при этом данные `SOCKS` (та же версия и прочие параметры) шли в `little-endian`? Куда копать?
Править исходники? Явно неверный подход. Можно, конечно, заменить `0x05` на `0x0500` и т. д., но тогда придется разбираться с протоколом `SOCKS`, чтобы выяснить длину каждого параметра. В Си есть функция `htons` и аналогичные, но они наоборот приводят к сетевому `big-endian`, а мне нужно к `little`.

Исходник сейчас такой:

```
// #define AUTH_ON 1
#define PORT 3003
#define BUFF_SIZE 1024

#ifdef AUTH_ON

  const char AuthLogin[] = "login";
  const char AuthPass[] = "pass";
  #define SOCKS5_METHOD 0x02      
#else

  #define SOCKS5_METHOD 0x00        
#endif

#include "sys/types.h"
#include "sys/socket.h"
#include "netinet/in.h"
#include "netdb.h"

typedef int SOCKET;
typedef int bool;
typedef int __stdcall;

#define SOCKET_ERROR -1
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1

#define false 0
#define true 1

#define SD_BOTH SHUT_RDWR

#define _malloc malloc
#define closesocket close

#define SOCKS_VERSION 0x05
#define SOCKS_SUCCESS 0x00
#define SOCKS_FAILURE 0x01
#define SOCKS_CONNECTION_REFUSED 0x05
#define SOCKS_CMD_NOT_SUPPORTED 0x07

typedef struct
{

  char* _ConnectStruct;
  SOCKET From;
  SOCKET To;
  char Buff[BUFF_SIZE];
  char* Error;

} SOCKSPIPE;

typedef SOCKSPIPE* LPSOCKSPIPE;

typedef struct _CONNECTSTRUCT
{

  SOCKSPIPE FromStruct;
  SOCKSPIPE ToStruct;
  char Error;

} CONNECTSTRUCT;

typedef CONNECTSTRUCT* LPCONNECTSTRUCT;

LPCONNECTSTRUCT CreateConnectStruct(SOCKET From, SOCKET To)
{
  LPCONNECTSTRUCT Result = (LPCONNECTSTRUCT)_malloc(sizeof(CONNECTSTRUCT));

  Result->FromStruct._ConnectStruct = (char*)Result;
  Result->FromStruct.From = From;
  Result->FromStruct.To = To;
  Result->FromStruct.Error = &(Result->Error);

  Result->ToStruct._ConnectStruct = (char*)Result;
  Result->ToStruct.From = To;
  Result->ToStruct.To = From;
  Result->ToStruct.Error = &(Result->Error);

  Result->Error = 0x00;

  return Result;
}

bool swrite(SOCKET s, char* Buff, int buff_size)
{
  int bytes;

  while(buff_size > 0)
  {
    bytes = send(s, Buff, buff_size, 0);

    if((bytes == 0)||(bytes == SOCKET_ERROR))
      return false;
    buff_size -= bytes;
    Buff += bytes;
  }

  return true;
}

bool sread(SOCKET s, char* Buff, int buff_size)
{
  int bytes;

  while(buff_size > 0)
  {
    bytes = recv(s, Buff, buff_size, 0);

    if((bytes == 0)||(bytes == SOCKET_ERROR))
      return false;

    buff_size -= bytes;
    Buff += bytes;
  }

  return true;
}

__stdcall SocksPipe(LPSOCKSPIPE PipeStruct)
{
  int bytes;

  do
  {
    bytes = recv(PipeStruct->From, PipeStruct->Buff, BUFF_SIZE, 0);

    if((bytes == 0) || (bytes == SOCKET_ERROR))
      break;

    if(*(PipeStruct->Error) & 0x01)
    {
      *(PipeStruct->Error) |= 0x02;
      return 0;
    }

    if(!swrite(PipeStruct->To, PipeStruct->Buff, bytes))
    {
      *(PipeStruct->Error) |= 0x02;
      return 0;
    }
  }
  while(!(*(PipeStruct->Error) & 0x01));

  if(*(PipeStruct->Error) & 0x01)
    *(PipeStruct->Error) |= 0x02;
  else
  {
    *(PipeStruct->Error) |= 0x01;
    shutdown(PipeStruct->From, SD_BOTH);
    shutdown(PipeStruct->To, SD_BOTH);
    closesocket(PipeStruct->From);
    closesocket(PipeStruct->To);

    while(!(*(PipeStruct->Error) & 0x02))
    {
      sleep(1);
    }

    free(PipeStruct->_ConnectStruct);
  }

  return 0;
}

bool Socks5SendCode(SOCKET s, char Code, char* TempBuff, char* ip, char* port)
{
  *(int*)TempBuff = 0x1000000 | (Code << 8) | SOCKS_VERSION;
  *(int*)(TempBuff + 4) = *(int*)ip;
  *(short*)(TempBuff + 8) = *(short*)port;

  return swrite(s, TempBuff, 10);
}

SOCKET Socks5ServConnect(SOCKET s, char* TempBuff, char* ip, u_short port)
{
  struct sockaddr_in saddr;
  SOCKET Redir = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if(Redir == INVALID_SOCKET)
    Socks5SendCode(s, SOCKS_FAILURE, TempBuff, ip, (char*)&port);
  else
  {
    bzero(&saddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(in_addr_t*)ip;
    saddr.sin_port = port;

    if(connect(Redir, (struct sockaddr*)&saddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1)
    {
      Socks5SendCode(s, SOCKS_CONNECTION_REFUSED, TempBuff, ip, (char*)&port);
      closesocket(Redir);
      Redir = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
  }
  return Redir;
}

bool Socks5CmdIsSupported(SOCKET s, char cmd, char* TempBuff, char* ip, char* port)
{
  if(cmd != 0x01) // 0x02 - bind; 0x03 - udp associate
  {
    Socks5SendCode(s, SOCKS_CMD_NOT_SUPPORTED, TempBuff, ip, port);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

bool Socks5GetCmd(SOCKET s, char* TempBuff, char* cmd, char* ip, char* port)
{
  struct hostent* hp;
  char DnLen;
  char AddrType;
  char Tmp[5];

  if(!sread(s, TempBuff, 4))
    return false;

  if((TempBuff[0] != SOCKS_VERSION)||(TempBuff[2] != 0x00))
    return false;

  *cmd = TempBuff[1];
  AddrType = TempBuff[3];

  switch(AddrType)
  {
    case 0x01: // ip v4
      if(!sread(s, ip, 4))
        return false;
      break;

    case 0x03: // domain name

      if(!sread(s, &DnLen, 1))
        return false;
      if(DnLen == 0)
        return false;
      if(!sread(s, TempBuff, DnLen))
        return false;
      TempBuff[DnLen] = 0x00;

      hp = gethostbyname(TempBuff);

      if(((int)hp == -1)||((int)hp == 0))
      {
        if(!sread(s, port, 2))
          return false;

        *(int*)(&Tmp) = 0x03000405;
        *(char*)(&Tmp + 4) = DnLen;

        if(swrite(s, Tmp, 5))
          if(swrite(s, TempBuff, DnLen))
            swrite(s, port, 2);

        return false;
      }
      else
        *(int*)ip = *(int*)hp->h_addr;

      break;

    case 0x04:  // ip v6, not supported
      *(int*)(&Tmp) = 0x04000805;

      if(sread(s, TempBuff, 16))
        if(sread(s, port, 2))
          if(swrite(s, Tmp, 4))
            if(swrite(s, TempBuff, 16))
              swrite(s, port, 2);

      return false;

    default:
      return false;
  }

  return sread(s, port, 2);
}

#ifdef AUTH_ON

  bool Socks5Auth(SOCKET s, char* TempBuff)
  {
    char Login[256];
    char LoginLen;
    char PassLen;
    char Status = '\xFF';

    if(!sread(s, TempBuff, 2))
      return false;

    LoginLen = TempBuff[1];

    if((TempBuff[0] != 0x01)||(LoginLen == 0))
      return false;

    if(!sread(s, Login, LoginLen+1))
      return false;

    PassLen = Login[LoginLen];

    if(!PassLen)
      return false;

    Login[LoginLen] = 0x00;

    if(!sread(s, TempBuff, PassLen))
      return false;

    TempBuff[PassLen] = 0x00;

    if((strcmp(AuthLogin, Login) == 0)&&(strcmp(AuthPass, TempBuff) == 0))
      Status = 0x00;

    *(short*)TempBuff = (Status << 8) | 0x01;

    if(!swrite(s, TempBuff, 2))
      return false;

    return (Status == 0x00);
  }

#endif

bool Socks5Accept(SOCKET s, char* TempBuff)
{
  char MethodsCount;
  char Cmd = '\xFF';

  if(!sread(s, TempBuff, 2))
    return false;

  MethodsCount = TempBuff[1];

  if((TempBuff[0] != SOCKS_VERSION)||(MethodsCount == 0))
    return false;

  if(!sread(s, TempBuff, MethodsCount))
    return false;

  do
  {
    MethodsCount--;

    if(TempBuff[MethodsCount] == SOCKS5_METHOD)
    {
      Cmd = TempBuff[MethodsCount];
      break;
    }
  }
  while(MethodsCount > 0);

  *(short*)TempBuff = (Cmd << 8) | SOCKS_VERSION;

  if(!swrite(s, TempBuff, 2))
    return false;

#ifdef AUTH_ON

  return (Cmd == 0xFF) ? false : Socks5Auth(s, TempBuff);
#else

  return (Cmd != 0xFF);
#endif

}

__stdcall AcceptThread(SOCKET s)
{
  SOCKET Redir;
  LPCONNECTSTRUCT ConnectStruct;
  char TempBuff[256];
  char cmd;
  char ip[4];
  u_short port;
  pid_t forkpid;

  if(Socks5Accept(s, TempBuff))
    if(Socks5GetCmd(s, TempBuff, &cmd, ip, (char*)&port))
      if(Socks5CmdIsSupported(s, cmd, TempBuff, ip, (char*)&port))
      {
        Redir = Socks5ServConnect(s, TempBuff, ip, port);

        if(Redir != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
          if(Socks5SendCode(s, SOCKS_SUCCESS, TempBuff, ip, (char*)&port))
          {
            ConnectStruct = CreateConnectStruct(s, Redir);
            forkpid = fork();
            if(forkpid != -1) {
                if(forkpid == 0) {
                    SocksPipe(&(ConnectStruct->ToStruct));
                }
            }
            SocksPipe(&(ConnectStruct->FromStruct));
            return 0;
          }
          closesocket(Redir);
        }
      }

  closesocket(s);
  return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  SOCKET s, accepted;
  struct sockaddr_in saddr;
  int saddr_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  pid_t forkpid;

  s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if(s != INVALID_SOCKET)
  {
    bzero(&saddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if(bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&saddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
      if(listen(s, 0) != SOCKET_ERROR)
        for(;;)
        {
          accepted = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&saddr, &saddr_size);

          if(accepted != INVALID_SOCKET)
          {
            forkpid = fork();
            if(forkpid != -1) {
                if(forkpid == 0) {
                    AcceptThread((void*)accepted);
                    break;
                }
            }
          }

        }

    closesocket(s);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MIPS-Options.html  не пробовали те опции что в начале указаны ? но если ключей нет, то socks очень простой протокол. быстро можно поправить. Кстати, в socks 5 версия - это 1 байт, если разработчик его пишет в пакет заодно со следующим байтом - он не прав.

Comment: @Mike, Говорю же, пробовал -meb и -mel для моего компилятора. Опять же, если собрать под little-endian, программа не подгрузит бибилотеки из прошивки модема, которые в big-endian, собирать отдельные библиотеки... нет уж, к тому же свободного места и памяти на модеме совсем мало.

Comment: Ну да, над кодом боюсь придется поработать. Им, получая на вход `char *` лень писать `TempBuff[0]=5; TempBuff[1]=Code; TempBuff[2]=0; TempBuff[3]=1`, они предпочитают все то же сделать в int `*(int*)TempBuff = 0x1000000 | (Code << 8) | SOCKS_VERSION` ... Собственно это весь socks 5 заголовок. Дальше идет порт и IP. В википедии его формат написан. К сожалению дальше по коду они применяют такую же технику.

Comment: И я бы не сказал, что править исходники это неправильный подход. Ибо разработчик этого чуда стремясь к слабоуловимой оптимизации наплевал на существование разного порядка байт и работает с однобайтыми по стандарту полями как с 4х байтными. А этот разработчик уверен, кстати, что у него int - это именно 4 байта. Он то как раз уверен ... только он и тут не прав

Comment: Более того, переход от pthreads к fork делает обработку ошибок неработоспособной (обратите внимание на `while(!(*(PipeStruct->Error) & 0x02))
    {
      sleep(1);
    }` и т.п.)

Comment: @Дмитрий, ну как же, есть функция обратного преобразования ntohs, которая приводит число к little-endian. Мало того, если покопаться в коде этих функций, то может выясниться, что он идентичен (где-то в исходниках видела использование одной и той же функции _swap()_ внутри обоих _htons()_ и _ntohs()_), так что вполне вероятно, что применяя одну из функций к одной переменной несколько раз, Вы будете получать то привычный, то сетевой, порядок байт.

Comment: @margosh, Насколько я понимаю, ntohs переводит из сетевого порядка в системный, а в моем случае это big-endian. В x86, конечно, получится little.

Comment: @Mike, Спасибо за подсказку. Поправил пару строк кода - заработало.